# Modular arithmetic problem from Chinese remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Take $p,q$ to be coprimes with $p<q<2p$. If $w,x,y,z$ are unknowns such that $w,x,y,z<\min(p,q)$ and we know $(wy+xz)\bmod (p+q)$, $(wz+xy)\bmod (p+q)$ $wy\bmod q$ and $xz\bmod p$ then are $w,x,y,z$ uniquely determined upto some symmetry?

Comment: Do you wish to constrain the signs of $w,x,y,z$?  Given a nonzero non-negative solution set, $(w,x,y,z)$, it happens that $(-w,-x,-y,-z)$ is another that satisfies your current constraints.

Comment: Please do not edit your existing question to ask a completely different question. You can simply start a new question.

Comment: It is same question. I forgot the syummetry part. What symmetry charatcerizes the solutions? Can we formulate all solutions in terms of some symmetry?

Comment: How is a future reader who comes to this thread to make sense of your constantly changing question and mysteriously vanishing comments?  A conversation happened here, but you have chosen to make it incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

No; switching $x$ and $z$, or $w$ and $y$, yields another solution. That is, given $(w,x,y,z)$, the 4-tuples $(w,z,y,x)$, $(y,x,w,z)$ and $(y,z,w,x)$ satisfy the same congruences.

Concretely, take $p=3$, $q=5$ and $(w,x,y,z)=(1,1,2,2)$. Then $wy+xz\equiv4\pmod{8}$ and $wy\equiv2\pmod{3}$ and $xz\equiv2\pmod{5}$. But the same congruences hold for $(w,x,y,z)=(2,2,1,1)$.

This shows that almost every choice of $p,q,w,x,y,z$ is a counterexample, which makes me wonder whether you have even thought about it at all.

Comment: @Serves So upto symmetry they are same? that is what I am curiou about?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Even ignoring the defects in the question, a "rescued" version of the question is hopeless.  There are primes and distinct quadruples (even ignoring sign and swap symmetries) that have the same residues you call out.

For $p=5,q=7$, a very easy computer search finds many distinct satisfying pairs of quadruples (where "$(u)_v$" means $u \pmod{v}$):
$$\begin{align}
(wy+&xz)_{p+q},& (w&y)_{q},& (x&z)_{p},& &(w,x,y,z)  \\
&2&  &1&  &1&  &(1,1,1,1),(2,2,4,3)  \\
&4&  &1&  &3&  &(1,1,1,3),(2,2,4,4)  \\
&3&  &2&  &1&  &(1,1,2,1),(3,2,3,3)  \\
&4&  &2&  &2&  &(1,1,2,2),(4,3,4,4)  \\
&5&  &2&  &3&  &(1,1,2,3),(3,2,3,4)  \\
&5&  &1&  &4&  &(1,2,1,2),(2,3,4,3)  \\
&6&  &2&  &4&  &(1,2,2,2),(3,3,3,3)  \\
&8&  &2&  &1&  &(1,2,2,3),(4,4,4,4)  \\
&10& &2&  &1&  &(3,1,3,1),(4,2,4,3)  \\
&0&  &2&  &3&  &(3,1,3,3),(4,2,4,4)  \\
&1&  &2&  &4&  &(3,2,3,2),(4,3,4,3)
\end{align}
$$
(I *think* this is all of them.  I may have omitted too may pairs as symmetrically redundant, but this doesn't change the content of this answer.)

Comment: sorry I corrected.

Comment: @AAAA : The answer to your miraculously vanishing comment is *also*, "no".  The first four, last two, and one starting with "$6$" rows of the table above have the same values of your additional constraint.

Comment: ok. That helps.